# Ping Tool to check if server is online

Tags: bash

Is this tool that I created from various SOF threads valid?  Will it work?  I want to have a ping test done to a server every minute.  If it fails 5 times in a row it sends an email out.  It then flushes and resets the script pretty much to check again.

```
#!/bin/bash
# ping checker tool

numOfFails=0
incrememnt=1
EMAILMESSAGE="/tmp/emailmessage.txt"

while true; do
    if ! ping -c 1 google.com ; then #if ping exits nonzero...
        numOfFails=$(($num + $increment))
    else
        numOfFails=0
    fi
    if ((numOfFails > 4)); then
        numOfFails=0
        echo "SAN is offline!" > $EMAILMESSAGE
        mail -s "SAN offline" "test@test.com" < $EMAILMESSAGE
    fi
    sleep 60 #check again in one minute
done
```

Comment: `if numOfFails > 4;` should probably be `if ((numOfFails > 4)); then` for a start. And ```if ! [ "`ping -c 1 google.com`" ]; then``` is probably `if ! ping -c 1 google.com ; then`

Comment: @user000001 you should suggest that as an answer, and also point out that it doesn't count 5 in a row, only 5 in total.

Comment: @thatotherguy That's why I added it as a comment. I didn't validate the whole thing... :)

Comment: @user000001 what about the edits now? better?

Comment: @MasterGberry Yea now it should work. But nothing compares to actually testing it

Comment: Why don't you use one of the many monitoring tools available?

Comment: Why not change move the ping command above the conditional? `ping -c 1 google.com; if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then ...`

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth I am, i want this as a backup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code won't work at all, this is a revised version:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ping checker tool

FAILS=0
EMAIL_ADDRESS="example@example.com"
SERVER="192.168.1.1"
SLEEP=60

while true; do
    ping -c 1 $SERVER >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then #if ping exits nonzero...
        FAILS=$[FAILS + 1]
    else
        FAILS=0
    fi
    if [ $FAILS -gt 4 ]; then
        FAILS=0
        echo "Server $SERVER is offline!" \
            | mail -s "Server offline" "$EMAIL_ADDRESS"
    fi
    sleep $SLEEP #check again in SLEEP seconds
done
```

Change `example@example.com` and `192.168.1.1` for your email address and the IP address of the server you are testing.  I recommend using and IP address instead of a hostname to prevent mixing name resolution errors with connection errors.

Please be advised that although this will work I would recommend running a slightly different script from cron instead of having it running continuously like you seem to want, when running from cron you would not need to monitor that the script is running since if it stops for some reason the monitoring of the server stops as well.

Something like this run from crontab every minute.

```
#!/bin/bash
# ping checker tool

TMP_FILE="/tmp/ping_checker_tool.tmp"
if [ -r $TMP_FILE ]; then
    FAILS=`cat $TMP_FILE`
else
    FAILS=0
fi
EMAIL_ADDRESS="example@example.com"
SERVER="192.168.1.1"

ping -c 1 $SERVER >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then #if ping exits nonzero...
    FAILS=$[FAILS + 1]
else
    FAILS=0
fi
if [ $FAILS -gt 4 ]; then
    FAILS=0
    echo "Server $SERVER is offline!" \
        | mail -s "Server offline" "$EMAIL_ADDRESS"
fi
echo $FAILS > $TMP_FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Pingdom.  It provides this service for you.

One thing you have not considered is once your site goes down, you will continue to get email messages every minute, until the site is up again, or until you stop this script.

A good approach is to switch states from reporting when the site is down to reporting when the site is up, once you have detected that it is down.   And then back again, once it is back up.

Essentially you one receive an email reporting 'site down', then another later on, hopefully, reporting 'site is up'.

Pingdom does this for you, very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I have been investigating how to do this so that I can activate/deactivate services depending on whether my phone is at home. I have come up with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST_TO_CHECK=<hostname>

if ping -qc 20 $HOST_TO_CHECK >/dev/null; then
    echo "Host $HOST_TO_CHECK is up"
else
    echo "Host $HOST_TO_CHECK is down"
fi
```

Replace **<hostname>** with the host you wish to check.

The script will ping the host 20 times.
The reason it does this is that my mobile doesn't always respond to pings immediately.

Obviously you can replace the echo commands with something to actually do something useful :-)

You can then schedule the script to check every 5 minutes by adding it to your crontab:

```
*/5 * * * * /opt/pingcheck.sh
```